# How to use jq for firehose metadata extraction in aggregated events

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, jql

I have this aggregated single event in firehose. When  using jq to create keys:values for I get the below error. My jq is like this

```
id:.id
users:users[].uuid
```

> Error: metadata extraction failed because JQ query failed. invalid jq query
> causing a single record to split into 2 or more.

```
{   "id":20
    "users": [
        {   "uuid":2330
            "first": "Stevie",
            "last": "Wonder"
        },
        {   "uuid":9033131
            "first": "Michael",
            "last": "Jackson"
        }
    ]
}
{   "id":30
    "users": [
        {   "uuid":984209302
            "first": "lower",
            "last": "harvest"
        },
        {   "uuid":8980323932
            "first": "Duncan",
            "last": "mighty"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I want to be able to create dynamicc partitioning using uuid.**

```
{   "id":20
        "users": [
            {   "uuid":2330
                "first": "Stevie",
                "last": "Wonder"
            }
]
},
{   "id":20
        "users": [
            {   "uuid":9033131
                "first": "Michael",
                "last": "Jackson"
            }
        ]
    }
},
    {   "id":30
        "users": [
            {   "uuid":984209302
                "first": "lower",
                "last": "harvest"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the part you need is explained in the manual's section on [object construction](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#object-construction).

This will put the objects in an array, which is close to your desired output.

```
jq -n '[ inputs | { id, "users": .users[] } ]'
```

But perhaps this is what you want.

```
jq '{ id, "users": .users[] }'
```

Comment: Assuming there is valid JSON, unlike in the question, I'm thinking the same.  https://jqplay.org/s/kJ8qeMKWxRS

Comment: Because Im doing this in was firehose I still get Error: metadata extraction failed because JQ query failed. invalid jq query causing a single record to split into 2 or more.